# U-boot will run on single core?

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, u-boot, smp

I am working on TI Jacinto6(ARM CortexA15) based board. I am understanding U-boot source.
As per start.S file, following assembly instructions are executed to disable L1 I/D cache and TLB. This instructions are from start.s(http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/cpu/armv7/start.S;h=fedd7c8f7e00d0427405173849e6c0743d6b886f;hb=524123a70761110c5cf3ccc5f52f6d4da071b959)

```
 mov     r0, #0                  @ set up for MCR
 mcr     p15, 0, r0, c8, c7, 0   @ invalidate TLBs
 mcr     p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 0   @ invalidate icache
 mcr     p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 6   @ invalidate BP array
 mcr     p15, 0, r0, c7, c10, 4  @ DSB
 mcr     p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 4   @ ISB
```

As per ARM documents CortexA15 is having 4 cores. 
The above code will disable the cache and TLB on the core which it is running, then what about the other cores cache and TLB. Will the U-boot source runs on only one core? If so then how other cores will be disabled?

Comment: Typically after a processor/system reset, only one core is enabled; everything else is quiescent or disabled.  Check the ARM documentation that you mentioned.    U-Boot will execute on only one core

Comment: "As per ARM documents CortexA15 is having 4 cores" - are you sure? The Cortex-A15 design may support configurations of _up to_ 4 cores per cluster, but everything I see on TI's site says the Jacinto 6 implements a dual-core configuration.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the info. So Kernel will enable the other cores while booting?, can you please share the kernel source link(git) which enables the other cores.

Comment: @Notlikethat CortexA15 having 4 cores as per the diagram @ http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a15.php .  Jacinto 6 is having CortexA15 and Cortex M4, can you please share the TI link which explains that Jacinto 6 is running with two cores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will the U-boot source runs on only one core?

The U-Boot binary (not the source) executes on only one processor core.
The functionality of a bootloader does not require parallel processing.
Also the Linux kernel expects only one core to be enabled when it starts.

> If so then how other cores will be disabled?

Typically after a processor/system reset, only one core is enabled; everything else is quiescent or disabled.

> So Kernel will enable the other cores while booting?

The OS, assuming it supports SMP (symmetric multiprocessors), will enable the other cores as part of its initialization.

> can you please share the kernel source link(git) which enables the other cores.

For an ARM Cortex-A9 quad-core (an A15 would be similar) the Linux kernel outputs:

```
Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Linux version 3.10.60+wandboard_1.0.2+1.0.0-wandboard (root@host) (gcc version 4.8.3 (crosstool-NG 1.19.0) ) #7 SMP Mon Dec 29 18:49:06 PST 2014
CPU: ARMv7 Processor [412fc09a] revision 10 (ARMv7), cr=10c53c7d
CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
Machine: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree), model: Wandboard Quad based on Freescale i.MX6 Quad
...  
L310 cache controller enabled
l2x0: 16 ways, CACHE_ID 0x410000c7, AUX_CTRL 0x32070000, Cache size: 1048576 B
...
CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
Setting up static identity map for 0x804bdd30 - 0x804bdd88
CPU1: Booted secondary processor
CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
CPU2: Booted secondary processor
CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
CPU3: Booted secondary processor
CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
Brought up 4 CPUs
SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (6324.22 BogoMIPS).
CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
devtmpfs: initialized
...
```

The Linux kernel begins execution of its C code in **start_kernel()** in [init/main.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c?v=3.10#L471).
The second procedure called is the ARM version of [smp_setup_processor_id()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c?v=3.10#L449), which is responsible for the `Booting Linux on physical CPU ...` message text.

Towards the end of **start_kernel()**, the ARM version of **check_bugs()** will invoke [check_writebuffer_bugs()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/fault-armv.c?v=3.10#L232), which is responsible for the `CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ...` message text.

At the end of **start_kernel()**, [rest_init()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c?v=3.10#L364) eventually initializes the other processor cores through the ARM version of [secondary_start_kernel()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/smp.c?v=3.10#L312) (`CPUn: Booted secondary processor`), invoked somehow through [smp_init()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/smp.c?v=3.10#L539) (`Brought up N CPUs`).